# Reset PerfPublisher on Hudson/Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have PerfPublisher v7.97 on a Hudson v2.1.2 server. Is it possible to reset the test report from this plugins without deleting and recreating the job ? (I do not think it is possible through the GUI, so I am more looking for a config file to delete or something like that). Help   [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/PerfPublisher+Plugin) did not help.

Thanks.